# How to restore NuGet packages in Visual Studio without a full NuGet reinstall

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a project downloaded from a GitHub repository.
I try to restore its NuGet packages, but I can't without the full reinstall.

There is a UI option that I'd like to use:

[image]

When I use it, it opens the Solution properties inside the Properties tab.

This is its settings:

[image]

When I try to use the *Clear the NuGet package cache*, I get the following unhandled exception:

[image]

As there are older references, if I use the `Update-Package -reinstall` command, every package will be updated to its latest version (unless I do it one by one...for each of the 47 packages...)

I deleted the .nuget folder and after rebuild, it remains empty.

So what are my options to use a working restore? Can I fix somehow the built-in command in Visual Studio?

Comment: look for a VS2019 update: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1015106/exception-occurred-exception-from-hresult-0x800200.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried most of the suggested actions without any success and eventually a *complete Visual Studio settings reset* was the solution.

You can do it by selecting *Tools->Import and Export settings* and then choosing *Reset all settings*. There is an option to save the current settings as backup but I didn't keep them due to their assumed corrupted state.

[image]

It appears to be the *nuclear option* but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

> So what are my options to use a working restore? Can I fix somehow the
> built-in command in Visual Studio?

Check whether the project from the github has a file called `packages.config`, if so, which approves that the project uses `packages.config` to manage nuget packages.

If the project used [packages.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config) nuget management format to manage the package and just delete `.nuget` folder,then rebuild your project, it did not restore the packages under `.nuget` folder It actually references the packages from the `packages` folder under the solution folder.

[image]

**So** you should also delete the `packages` folder from the solution folder and then rebuild your project. Then, the packages will be restored under `.nuget` folder.(it is the specific feature of `packages.config`).

=====================================================

If it does not work and to handle the error shown in the screenshot, please try the following suggestions:

**Suggestion**

**1)** open `Package Source` under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**NuGet Package Manager**--> **Package Source** and then uncheck other feeds except `nuget.org`. Please retain the

[image]

Also, check whether you have a `nuget.config` file under the solution folder or above folder, and if so, please check if it has a key called [globalPackagesFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#config-section).

Like

```
<add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="xxxx" />
```

Please **delete** it directly and then restart your project.

More info you can refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses).

**2)** close VS, delete global `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`.

**Also**, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder and restart VS to regenerate the `nuget.config` file.

**3)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**

**4)** If there is any update for VS, please update it.

Comment: There is no packages.config, it uses `PackageReference` in the csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today, to solve it I went to Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Manage Nuget Packages for Solution.  Select any package and uninstall then reinstall that same package.  After it's finished installing, all references in the Solution should be updated.